# python on windows cmd with os.popen(): UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, windows, cmd, character-encoding, popen

Code:

```
import os

ipconfig1 = os.popen("ipconfig /all")
ipconfig2 = ipconfig1.read()
```

The `ipconfig` output has non-latin symbols. Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "getIt.py", line 4, in <module>
    ipconfig2 = ipconfig1.read()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 2948: character maps to <undefined>
```

What I tried:

```
pip install win-unicode-console
```

and (yes, one of those is stupid but I tried it desperately)

```
ipconfig2 = ipconfig1.decode('utf8').read()
ipconfig2 = ipconfig1.encode('utf8').read()
```

in bat file: `chcp 65001`, `set PYTHONIOENCODING=:replace` and `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8`

Neither of those works. How to do it properly?

Comment: That means that the file you are reading is not encoded in the encoding format your computer is trying to use. In UTF8, (one of the most common) the character \x98 is a continuation character, meaning it's only valid with a specific second character after it. You need to find the right encoding for the file, or tell python to ignore errors `with open(file, errors='ignore')`

Comment: When writing to a pipe, ipconfig.exe defaults to OEM encoding. If that's good enough for your needs, use `output = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig /all', encoding='oem')`.

Comment: If you need Unicode, ipconfig.exe supports an `OutputEncoding` environment variable that can be set to "unicode" (UTF-16LE) or "utf8" -- and also to legacy "ansi". (Support for this variable is not universal in the classic Windows command-line tools. Most are fixed at OEM or ANSI, and some use the console input or output codepage.) For example, use `environ = os.environ.copy();` `environ['OutputEncoding'] = 'utf8';` `output = subprocess.check_output('ipconfig /all', env=environ, encoding='utf-8-sig')`. This uses "utf-8-sig" to skip the initial byte order mark that ipconfig.exe writes.